# reading ComboBox value that DisplayMember and ValueMember are filled by Dictionary

Tags: c#, combobox, .net-4.0

I had made `Dictionary` as a Datasource for a `ComboBox` then save `ValueMember` of that `ComboBox` into database

```
Dictionary<string, int> GravelCount = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    {"val1",1},
    {"val2",2},
};
CB_Place.DataSource = new BindingSource(GravelCount, null);
CB_Place.DisplayMember = "Key";
CB_Place.ValueMember = "Value";
CB_Place.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

now when I am trying to read it is `ValueMember` and show the `DisplayMember` as shown below at line `CB_Place.SelectedItem = sqlReader[1].ToString();` nothing happen and `combobox` not filled `ValueMember`

```
public int GetPersonification()
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRJDconnstr"].ToString();
    string cmdStr = @"SELECT SIZ,
                                             PLACE,
                                             ONE_OR_MORE,
                                             R_OR_L,
                                             EKO_OR_ASH,
                                             NOTICE
                                     FROM PERSONIFICATION
                                   WHERE ID=@ID;";

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
    {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = cmdStr;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = tb_id.text;

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                TB_Size.Text = sqlReader[0].ToString();
                CB_Place.SelectedItem = sqlReader[1].ToString();
                TB_Note.Text = sqlReader[5].ToString();
            }
    }
}
```

I also tried to use `ValueMember` and `((KeyValuePair<string,int>)CB_type.SelectedItem).Value.ToString();`

Comment: Since you said you have the ValueMember set, use `CB_Place.SelectedValue = ...`  Your function doesn't return a value.

Comment: @LarsTech same I got nothing I tried

Comment: Show the code where you are setting the CB_Place data properties.

Comment: @LarsTech post upate it please

Comment: This code tries to assign a string to the SelectedItem of the combobox. This makes no sense. Can you explain better what are you trying to do here?. The combobox has already its datasource set before this code?

Comment: `CB_Place.SelectedValue = 2;` works, `CB_Place.SelectedValue = "2";` does not.  Use integers in place of strings where appropriate.  Same with your parameter.

Comment: @LarsTech I am trying to use `combobox` with `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` without using database so I made that dictionary

Comment: @LarsTech `CB_Place.SelectedValue = 2;` and  `CB_Place.SelectedValue = "2";` both are not working

Comment: Using `CB_Place.SelectedValue = 2` works for me with your DataSource code.  Does your query work?

Comment: @LarsTech no it is not working

Comment: CB_GravelCount and CB_Place are different controls.

Comment: @LarsTech sorry miss typos post corrected

Comment: Ignore your GetPersonification code.  Replace `CB_GravelCount.SelectedIndex = -1;` with `CB_GravelCount.SelectedValue = 2;` in your first code block and you will get "val2" presented.

Comment: @LarsTech Yes I get the `val2` but why I am not get it in `GetPersonification`

Comment: You would have to debug your code to see what happens when the code reaches that line.  You need to convert `sqlReader[1].ToString();` to an integer value.  Use int.TryParse.